# React to a message the bot posted

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I react to a message the bot previously posted?

I've tried this but that doesn't work.

```
return message.channel.send(`Test message`);
message.react('');
```

Comment: If this is in the same function `return` will stop the execution of your function, so `message.react()` will never be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message.channel.send('test').then(msg=>msg.react(''));
```

That's because message.channel.send returns a promise that resolves when the message is sent, and 'then' we can add a reaction to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the sent message in a new variable before reacting to it :

```
var messageSent = message.channel.send(`Test message`);
messageSent.react('');
```